# Jsf ActionListener for custom security implementation

Tags: java, security, jsf, actionlistener

I've developed custom ActionListener:

```
public class SecureActionListener extends ActionListenerImpl implements ActionListener {

    private ActionListener _delegate;

    public SecureActionListener(ActionListener delegate) {
        _delegate = delegate;
    }


    @Override
    public void processAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        super.processAction(actionEvent);
    }
}
```

and configured it like that:

```
   <application>
        <action-listener>
            com.example.SecureActionListener
        </action-listener>
    </application>
```

Can this SecureActionListener class be expanded in such a way as to allow to read backing bean method signature together with its annotations?

I want this SecureActionListener to throw exception when there is a call to a backing bean method annotated with @Secured(roleName) and user has not required role.

Comment: It might be easier to create your own commandButton component and have a `secured` attribute. `<my:commandButton secured="role" ...`. In ICEFaces for example most of the components have an enabledOnUserRole attribute.

Comment: last time I went thru http://cameotutorials.blogspot.com/2010/03/beginning-java-ee-6-tutorial-part-3.html. Take a look. it might be what you're looking for.